# How to Debug a project that includes ASP classic, ASP.NET , C# and VB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

I have a website running on .NET 2.0. This website includes pages written in asp.net, asp classic some in VB and some in C#. 
I created a solution file in visual studio and it just brings the aspx and aspx.cs pages. Therefore I cant run the website locally since it is missing the asp classic pages and even if I add asp classic pages to that project in visual studio, it still does not work.
Any idea how to debug this project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What are you using as your local server?  The built in one which comes with comes with VS doesn't support Classic ASP, but you can configure VS to use IIS or IIS Express as its testing server.

VS gives you a bit of intellisense for classic ASP but for debugging, the easiest approach is to use the detailed error messages which IIS gives you

Comment: I just want to run the website on visual studio and locahost to be able to debug that. I dont think if I run the app on the IIS of my machine I would be able to doebugging.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean here.  Localhost on Win 7 pro usually means the local version of IIS on your machine, and the standard way to debug Classic ASP is via the error messages which are displayed by the page in the browser - they pinpoint the page and the line where the error is occurring.  Are you getting syntax highlighting for your classic asp code in VS?  I seem to remember it was pulled for VS2008 and restored in VS2008 SP1

Comment: Yes, you definitely need SP1 with VS2008

Comment: I am running on windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 Pro

Comment: I have 2012 and it works in that, but I don't have 2013 I'm afraid.  .asp files aren't compiled so the don't need to be covered by the solution file.  Even if you can't see them in the solution pane you should still be able to open them through Ctrl+O then navigate to directory